# Interpretation of random Forest result obtained from 'randomForestExplainer' package

Tags: r, machine-learning, data-visualization, random-forest

I am using Random Forest analysis on my data set where all the variables, both X and Y, are categorical in nature. I have obtained very interesting results of analysis using randomForestExpaliner package. but most of the graphs are not clear to me. So, I need help. If someone has applied this package, would you please explain the meaning of graphical representations?

Thanks in advance

Tanzila

Comment: Could you please provide the graphs (or graphs similar to the ones) you have at moment as well as context regarding your data?

Comment: Yes, I can provide you the graph. here I cannot find any option to attach an html file. I can send you if you provide me your email address.